# Regex to caputure data type and field length in multiline definition file

Tags: regex

I tried this on Regex101 but I couldn't figure this out. I have a definition file that contains many definitions (sample output below). I'm trying to find only definitions where the datatype is equal to 4 and the maxlength is 0.

I'm close but my regex will match too much.

Here is what I have:

```
/(datatype\s+: 4[\s\S]*?(maxlength\s+:\s0))/g
```

This does match the cases that I want but also will match the case where datatype is 4 but maxlength is not 0 until it finds the next occurrence of manxlength = 0.

Sample data (sorry, it's long):

```
field {
   id             : 536870914
   name           : Set Field (Submit Mode)
   datatype       : 4
   fieldtype      : 1
   create-mode    : 2
   option         : 2
   timestamp      : 1489159658
   owner          : John Smith
   last-changed   : John Smith
   length-units   : 0
   maxlength      : 0
   clob-store-opt : 0
   menu-style     : 1
   qbe-match-op   : 1
   fulltext-optns : 0
   permission     : 12\1
}
field {
   id             : 536870915
   name           : Schema Name
   datatype       : 4
   fieldtype      : 1
   create-mode    : 2
   option         : 1
   timestamp      : 1165057260
   owner          : John Smith
   last-changed   : John Smith
   length-units   : 0
   maxlength      : 30
   clob-store-opt : 0
   menu-style     : 1
   qbe-match-op   : 1
   fulltext-optns : 0
   permission     : 12\1
}
field {
   id             : 536870916
   name           : Type
   datatype       : 4
   fieldtype      : 1
   create-mode    : 2
   option         : 1
   timestamp      : 1165057260
   owner          : John Smith
   last-changed   : John Smith
   length-units   : 0
   maxlength      : 30
   clob-store-opt : 0
   menu-style     : 2
   qbe-match-op   : 1
   fulltext-optns : 0
   permission     : 12\1
}
field {
   id             : 536870917
   name           : Set Field (Query Mode)
   datatype       : 4
   fieldtype      : 1
   create-mode    : 2
   option         : 2
   timestamp      : 1489159658
   owner          : John Smith
   last-changed   : John Smith
   length-units   : 0
   maxlength      : 0
   clob-store-opt : 0
   menu-style     : 1
   qbe-match-op   : 1
   fulltext-optns : 0
   permission     : 12\1
}
```

Also note that this is a very limited sample and there could be hundreds of these fields with different values.

Comment: I suspect you need [`/(datatype\s+: 4\b(?:(?!datatype\s+: \d)[\s\S])*?(maxlength\s+:\s0\b))/g`](https://regex101.com/r/uS9914/1)

Comment: That's it @WiktorStribiżew. You should post that as the answer and I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to temper the `[\s\S]*?` with a negative lookahead so as to build a [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat):

```
/(datatype\s+: 4\b(?:(?!datatype\s+: \d)[\s\S])*?(maxlength\s+:\s0\b))/g
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uS9914/1/)

The `(?:(?!datatype\s+: \d)[\s\S])*?` matches any char (`[\s\S]`), zero or more repetitions, as few as possible, that is not a starting point of the `datatype\s+: \d` (a `datatype` substring, `\s+` - one or more whitespaces, `:`, a space and a digit (`\d`).